# Laravel migration did not work

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-artisan, migrate

When i give command "`php artisan migrate`" it gives me error :

```
base table or view already exists: 1050 table 'users' already exists.
```

And does not update my DB's table. I rolled back and migrate it again but did not have any effect on DB, I create new project but it gives error too on the this command.

Comment: Drop the table and re-run migrations... or better if you are in dev, just re-create whole DB;

Comment: you don't need to drop the whole database. do as I described below in my answer

Comment: when working with migration it is good to run these 2 commands before migrating`composer dump-autoload && php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: @IvoHrádek I did these but did not work

Answer (score 0):

In your migrations make this check first

```
  Schema::hasTable('users');
```

if you don't have data, you can drop the columns manually first.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your migration is creating a table `users` in DB. This error simply means that table `users already exits` in such DB, so it can't be created.

What you can actually do, is to create a new empty DB or re-create your whole DB in case you can afford loosing your data, which I assume from your post.

Rollback undo only last migration step. You could possibly run:

```
$ php artisan migrate:rollback --step=2 # rollback two last migrations
```

or

```
$ php artisan migrate:reset # rollback all migrations
```

I suggest you to go through [Database: Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#rolling-back-migrations), so you will gain more knowledge about DB migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Because you ran the migration, there is a reference of the ran migration in the `migrations` table in your database. You need to manually delete that record in order for you to run the same migration again.

`migration` table keeps a track of the migration you run. before the migration actually happen Laravel writes a record to `migration` table.

If an error occur, migration fails but the reference record exists. hence the error

> base table or view already exists: 1050 table 'users' already exists.

The easiest way to handle this is, fix the issue with the migration file, remove the reference record from migration table and run the migration again.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps below:

first of all check your current migration status 
`php artisan migrate:status`

skip already imported tables and look for new migration files and remove create statement from your new migration files.

The issue here is that your new migration files may contain create statement rather then alter/drop etc.

once you fix that statement try running

`php artisan migrate`